# Gmail flags email as spam if it contains link to my website

Tags: email, spam, gmail

If anywhere within body of the email I place link to my website in format `<a href="http://mywebsite.com">more info here</a>` , it gets flagged as spam

I tested many different combinations and interesting thing is that it's only link to this particular website (my website) in which case email goes to spam. I tried few other website links, all I changed was href="" attribute and email is NOT marked as spam

I'm sending email from my hosting to gmail. On web server I have installed postfix and I'm managing email server on my own. I added SPF and DKIM records correctly so I dont think this would cause any problems. This is the same web server where I have website hosted, same website whose link is marked as spam in gmail. Any other emails which I send from this server to gmail without my website link in content are valid and are NOT going to spam

Now, could this be related to my site ranking in google? I wonder which factors could possibly use to send emails with my website link to spam. My site rank is not so bad (but not highly ranked either), it's not penalized as far as I know, I used couple of web services to test and it looked fine. It's also indexed properly and I can see it in google search results for relevant keywords

If anyone can provide more infos about this I would appreciate it

Comment: The IP address of your server may be flagged by Google. Has the IP address been previously used by anyone else in the last couple of years? have you been a good boy/girl and 'NOT' sent out mass campaigns to Gmail? Are you sending emails using SMTP authentication?

Comment: Is the e-mail you are sending from postfix being just forwarded to Gmail?

Comment: @SimonHayter no it hasn't been used by anyone as far as I know

Comment: @Mike it's not forwarded, I'm sending email via PHP's mail function and mail server configuration is in postfix config file

Comment: @Zack you should inspect your postfix log usually in /var/log/mail.log for messages from Gmail, then search the errors and you will find more information there. It is more of a Server Fault topic, not for this forum. It should not be about your site ranking, but probably about bad postfix setup.

Answer (score 3):

From [Google's bulk senders guidelines](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en#unsub):

> While Gmail works hard to deliver all legitimate mail to a user's inbox, it's possible that some legitimate messages may be marked as spam. Gmail does not accept 'whitelisting' requests from bulk senders, and we can't guarantee that all of your messages will bypass our spam filters. To make sure our users receive all the mail they'd like to, we've provided them with a method for sending us feedback about messages flagged as spam -- users have the option of clicking a 'Not spam' button for each message flagged by our spam filters. We listen to users' reports, and correct problems in order to provide them with the best user experience. As long as our users don't consider your mail as spam, you shouldn't have inbox delivery problems.

To solve the issue, you would need to send some messages to people and have them hit the "Not Spam" button or add the "from" email address to their contacts.